# How to add the dot to htaccess when setting up MAMP?

Tags: .htaccess

I set up MAMP so I can set up extensionless URLs on a client site, which I've never done before. I'm using MAC OS 10.7.x. I set up the ports as 80, 7888 and 3306.  I use Fetch for FTP and have show hidden files turned on.  I write html but not php or any other scripting language.

I have a static HTML client site loaded into the MAMP/htdocs folder and the website is working except for the includes because I can't add the dot to the htaccess. I do this all the time on web servers.

I opened the current htaccess located in my client file (not in MAMP), with my text editor (BBedit) then tried to save it with the dot and the finder will not let me do it.

As a test, I then opened Mamp/htdocs/client and at the same time opened the active website via FTP and drug the current htaccess file with the dot into that folder. However I can't tell that it did anything. And even if it did, it would be invisible and then I couldn't edit it.

I've spent about 8 hours searching the internet for a solution to this problem, and discussing the same issue in a well known apache forum, and nobody seems to know how to do this (other than telling me to open in text editor and resave, which isn't working).

I hope someone here can steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem completely, but I know 2 ways to have more control in Mac OSX concerning file naming:

1. http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/27025/secrets
   This software allows you to set some hidden setting, like show all hidden files
2. Open a terminal and use something like:

   $ sudo mv htacces .htaccess

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use a better editor, which shows hidden files on its file browser, e.g. SublimeText 3 or go to the Finder preferences and show hidden files in general.